# Do we always have a choice of state variables, and how is temperature in general a state function?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am reading Steane's fantastic *Thermodynamics: A Complete Undergraduate Course* and am a bit stumped as to the assertion being made that, for example, temperature is a state function.

Suppose I model my cup of water as a simple pV system. Fixing p = 1 atm, then it is a fact that "if a kilogram of water has a volume 1000.1 $cm^3$ at 1 atmosphere, its temperature could be either 2 or 7 degrees Celsius". How then is it fair to think of temperature as a state function? I have chosen to specify two DOF for my simple system (which has two independent DOF), and yet temperature is not uniquely specified. This seems to fly in the face of the argument Steane makes that temperature is uniquely specified by state. He seems to add that there is a choice of state variables (perhaps VT) which uniquely specifies the system, but I'm not sure I understand why that rescues T as a state function.

The direct quote from Steane about temperature as a state function is (here R is a reference system used to empirically define temperature by virtue of the state in which it is in equilibrium with the system being probed):

> We have shown that every equilibrium state of every system has a temperature, defined by the value θ, that identifies which standard state of R it is in thermal equilibrium with. This temperature is a single-valued function of the state variables. For a pV system it can be written
> $$\theta = \theta(p,V).$$

Comment: "its temperature could be either 2 or 7 degrees Celsius". How did they get these values?

Comment: @BobD From experiment, water < 4 C expands as it cools.

Comment: @Ben I'm questioning how they came up with two different temperatures for the same specific volume, not the fact that it expands < 4 C

Comment: @BobD The relationship between temperature and volume at constant pressure is a curve with a minimum at 4 degrees. If you only know the volume, there are two possible temperatures. If you know the temperature, there is only one possible volume.

Comment: @Ben First of all, you need to use the specific volume since it is the specification of any two intensive properties. Secondly, if you use the Engineering Toolbox on line calculator for 2 C and 7 C you get two different specific volumes.

Comment: I acknowledge not knowing the formula they used, but they said it is valid for 0-100 C and 1 atm. The website is generally reliable.

Comment: @BobD How did you conclude that specific volume "is the specification of any two intensive properties"? This is only true if the relationship is monotonic. For water it is not.

Comment: It is for most materials. I expect the textbook chose water specifically to make this point.

Comment: @Ben Monotonic what? To quote from the reference handbook for the FE exam in thermodynamics for getting a PE license in the US: "For a single-phase pure component, specification of any two *intensive*, independent properties properties is sufficient to fix all the rest".

Comment: @Ben check this out: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/water-specific-volume-weight-d_661.html

Comment: Engineering toolbox for me gives 1.00009 at 1 C and 1.00013 at 7 C, with 1.00004 at 4 C https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-specific-volume-weight-d_661.html

Comment: Engineering toolbox Gives 1.0001 at 0.8 C and same at 6.5 C.

Comment: @BobD Perhaps I have misunderstood what an intensive property is, and perhaps volume is not one, I don't know, not having a PE license, whatever one of those is.

Comment: @bobd Anyway the relationship between temperature and volume is monotonic for almost all materials, water is very much the odd man out. I believe rubber is also weird in a similar way but I don't recall the details.

Comment: Water is an exception to the two independent property rule between 0 and 4 C. You may find the following helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133917/are-pressure-and-volume-not-independent-properties-in-liquid-water

Answer (score 0):

Water is an unusual substance.

Most materials expand as they get warmer and contract as they get cooler. This means that at higher temperatures either the volume increases, or the pressure increases, so that knowing any two of the temperature, pressure, and volume, will allow you to calculate the other.

Water is unusual because below 4 degrees Celsius it expands. This means that you can no longer use pressure and volume to derive temperature; instead temperature becomes compulsory.

With the temperature and pressure you can get the volume, and with the temperature and volume you can get the pressure, but with the pressure and volume, you may not be able to get a unique value for the temperature.

This is the sense in which temperature is a state variable. It is the one you can't do without.

Now you may well ask, "why does the textbook say For a pV system it can be written
$θ=θ(p,V)$."

I expect the answer is that "water is not a well-behaved $pV$ system under 4 degrees" and the textbook was drawing your attention to the fact that not every system is a $pV$ system.

In physics, in engineering, and in life in general, things are well-behaved and well-understood within limits. Outside those limits, the regular equations we learn stop working.

Comment: "but with the pressure and volume, you may not be able to get a unique value for the temperature." I agree with that. But with the same pressure and specific volume you will have a unique temperature.

Comment: @BobD I am sure the FE exam advice is adequate for engineering because you don't often make things out of water. In physics we have to accept that nothing we know is the absolute truth, there are only more accurate theories.

Comment: Forget the FE exam reference. Did you check out the website I gave you? Do you dispute their data?

Comment: @BobD Engineering toolbox gives specific volume of 1.0001 at 0.8 C and same at 6.5 C. This disagrees with the textbook quote but makes the same point, it does not uniquely determine the temperature from the volume and pressure.

Comment: Point made, I hadn't noticed that. I stand by the FE exam definition specifying "intensive" properties, but clearly water is an exception. In any event, a related post is here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133917/are-pressure-and-volume-not-independent-properties-in-liquid-water

Comment: @BobD It seems you are a successful engineer while I am a failed physicist :-) Merry Christmas and happy engineering.

Comment: I have followed you and you are by no means a "failed physicist". As for me, I'm more a "jack of all trades and master of none" with the possible exception of 40+ yrs safety engineering experience. Merry Christmas to you too, and a Happy New Year!